# Facebook sharer gets title from content of HTML element

Tags: url, facebook-sharer, facebook-opengraph, hashbang

I am working on a single page website with multiple Facebook 'Share this' buttons. The main URL is ie.:

http://wishdesign.nl/fora/fb.sharer.htm (working demo URL)

The Facebook sharer URL would then be:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwishdesign.nl%2Ffora%2ffb.sharer.htm

Click the last link and you will see that the shared title is the Open Graph title "Test title" that was set in the meta tags. So far, so good.

But each section on the page has a button that shares that specific section through a URL with a hash bang in it, as in:

http://wishdesign.nl/fora/fb.sharer.htm#section-b

The Facebook share URL would become:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwishdesign.nl%2Ffora%2ffb.sharer.htm%23section-b

The addition of "#section-b" is helpful so that visitors are automatically redirected to the right section on the page, but... **Facebook also uses the content of the section as the shared title!** And when the section has quite some content, the title is pretty long.

Is there any way to influence this? I tried settings title, og:title and property:og:title attributes on the HTML element with ID "section-b", but non seemed to work.

Anybody's got a clue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sharer.php has been deprecated for quite some time now. I wouldn't spend time troubleshooting this and mode to the like button instead. There is no guarantee how much longer sharer.php will continue to work. Many people are already reporting that it has stopped working for them.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your quick reply. I was using sharer.php through addthis.com's widgets. And it seems that competitor sharethis.com also uses sharer.php. Tomorrow I am going to do some more research on this...

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ it actually is deprecated in favor of the Like button.